# Is it possible to open up and execute a Visual Studio C++ Win32 Console Application project with Visual Studio 6.0 C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, console

My school still uses MS VS 6.0 C++, don't ask why...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio You are using to develop the application?

Comment: Oh I have forgotten, I am using Visual C++ 2010

Comment: Wow, are you talking about a high school?

Comment: I am talking about a college...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS 6 can't open a VS 2010 project file directly.

You can create a new workspace in VS 6, and add your existing files to it.

Chances are, however, that the code won't compile -- VC++ 6 is quite old (predates the 1998 standard) so a lot of modern code won't work with it. Depending on how you've written your code, porting it to work with VC++ 6 may be anywhere from fairly trivial to essentially a complete rewrite from the ground up.